# Partial derivative in gradient descent for two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I've started taking an [online machine learning class](http://www.ml-class.org/), and the first learning algorithm that we are going to be using is a form of linear regression using gradient descent. I don't have much of a background in high level math, but here is what I understand so far.

Given $m$ number of items in our learning set, with $x$ and $y$ values, we must find the best fit line $h_\theta(x) = \theta_0+\theta_1x$ . The cost function for any guess of $\theta_0,\theta_1$ can be computed as:

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1) = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta(x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2$$

where $x^{(i)}$ and $y^{(i)}$ are the $x$ and $y$ values for the $i^{th}$ component in the learning set. If we substitute for $h_\theta(x)$,

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1) = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m(\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)})^2$$

Then, the goal of gradient descent can be expressed as

$$\min_{\theta_0, \theta_1}\;J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$$

Finally, each step in the gradient descent can be described as:

$$\theta_j := \theta_j - \alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j} J(\theta_0,\theta_1)$$

for $j = 0$ and $j = 1$ with $\alpha$ being a constant representing the rate of step.

I have no idea how to do the partial derivative. I have never taken calculus, but conceptually I understand what a derivative represents. The instructor gives us the partial derivatives for both $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ and says not to worry if we don't know how it was derived. (I suppose, technically, it is a computer class, not a mathematics class) However, I would very much like to understand this if possible. Could someone show how the partial derivative could be taken, or link to some resource that I could use to learn more? I apologize if I haven't used the correct terminology in my question; I'm very new to this subject.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The answer above is a good one, but I thought I'd add in some more "layman's" terms that helped me better understand concepts of partial derivatives. The answers I've seen here and in the Coursera forums leave out talking about the chain rule, which is important to know if you're going to get what this is doing...

---

It's helpful for me to think of partial derivatives this way: the variable you're
focusing on is treated as a variable, the other terms just numbers. Other key
concepts that are helpful:

- For "regular derivatives" of a simple form like $F(x) = cx^n$ , the derivative is simply $F'(x) = cn \times x^{n-1}$
- The derivative of a constant (a number) is 0.
- Summations are just passed on in derivatives; they don't affect the derivative. Just copy them down in place as you derive.

Also, it should be mentioned that the [chain
rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) is being used. The chain rule says
that (in clunky laymans terms), for $g(f(x))$, you take the derivative of $g(f(x))$,
treating $f(x)$ as the variable, and then multiply by the derivative of $f(x)$. For
our cost function, think of it this way:

$$ g(\theta_0, \theta_1) = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left(f(\theta_0,
\theta_1)^{(i)}\right)^2 \tag{1}$$

$$ f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = \theta_0 + \theta_{1}x^{(i)} -
y^{(i)} \tag{2}$$

To show I'm not pulling funny business, sub in the definition of $f(\theta_0,
\theta_1)^{(i)}$ into the definition of $g(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ and you get:

$$ g(f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\theta_0 +
\theta_{1}x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}\right)^2 \tag{3}$$

This is, indeed, our entire cost function.

Thus, the partial derivatives work like this:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} g(\theta_0, \theta_1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial
\theta_0} \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left(f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}\right)^2 = 2
\times \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left(f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}\right)^{2-1} = \tag{4}$$

$$\frac{1}{m}
\sum_{i=1}^m f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}$$

In other words, just treat $f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}$ like a variable and you have a
simple derivative of $\frac{1}{2m} x^2 = \frac{1}{m}x$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} (\theta_0 + \theta_{1}x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) \tag{5}$$

And $\theta_1, x$, and $y$ are just "a number" since we're taking the derivative with
respect to $\theta_0$, so the partial of $g(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ becomes:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} f(\theta_0, \theta_1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} (\theta_0 + [a \
number][a \ number]^{(i)} - [a \ number]^{(i)}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0}
\theta_0 = 1 \tag{6}$$

So, using the chain rule, we have:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} g(f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} g(\theta_0, \theta_1) \frac{\partial}{\partial
\theta_0}f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} \tag{7}$$

And subbing in the partials of $g(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ and $f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}$
from above, we have:

$$ \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} \frac{\partial}{\partial
\theta_0}f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\theta_0 +
\theta_{1}x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}\right) \times 1 = \tag{8}$$

$$ \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\theta_0 + \theta_{1}x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}\right)$$

---

What about the derivative with respect to $\theta_1$?

Our term $g(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ is identical, so we just need to take the derivative
of $f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}$, this time treating $\theta_1$ as the variable and the
other terms as "just a number." That goes like this:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} (\theta_0 + \theta_{1}x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) \tag{9}$$

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial
\theta_1} f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} ([a \ number] +
\theta_{1}[a \ number, x^{(i)}] - [a \ number]) \tag{10}$$

Note that the "just a number", $x^{(i)}$, *is* important in this case because the
derivative of $c \times x$ (where $c$ is some number) is $\frac{d}{dx}(c \times x^1) =
c \times 1 \times x^{(1-1=0)} = c \times 1 \times 1 = c$, so the number will carry
through. In this case that number is $x^{(i)}$ so we need to keep it. Thus, our
derivative is:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = 0 + (\theta_{1})^1
x^{(i)} - 0 = 1 \times \theta_1^{(1-1=0)} x^{(i)} = 1 \times 1 \times x^{(i)} =
x^{(i)} \tag{11}$$

Thus, the entire answer becomes:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} g(f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} g(\theta_0, \theta_1) \frac{\partial}{\partial
\theta_1} f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = \tag{12}$$

$$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} \frac{\partial}{\partial
\theta_1}f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\theta_0 +
\theta_{1}x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}\right) x^{(i)}$$

---

A quick addition per @Hugo's comment below. Let's ignore the fact that we're dealing with vectors at all, which drops the summation and $fu^{(i)}$ bits. We can also more easily use real numbers this way.

$\require{cancel}$

Let's say $x = 2$ and $y = 4$.

So, for part 1 you have:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} (\theta_0 + \theta_{1}x - y)$$

Filling in the values for $x$ and $y$, we have:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} (\theta_0 + 2\theta_{1} - 4)$$

We only care about $\theta_0$, so $\theta_1$ is treated like a constant (any number, so let's just say it's 6).

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} (\theta_0 + (2 \times 6) - 4) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0} (\theta_0 + \cancel8) = 1$$

Using the same values, let's look at the $\theta_1$ case (same starting point with $x$ and $y$ values input):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} (\theta_0 + 2\theta_{1} - 4)$$

In this case we *do* care about $\theta_1$, but $\theta_0$ is treated as a constant; we'll do the same as above and use 6 for it's value:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} (6 + 2\theta_{1} - 4) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1} (2\theta_{1} + \cancel2) = 2 = x$$

The answer is 2 because we ended up with $2\theta_1$ and we had *that* because $x = 2$.

Hopefully the clarifies a bit on why in the first instance (wrt $\theta_0$) I wrote "just a number," and in the second case (wrt $\theta_1$) I wrote "just a number, $x^{(i)}$. While it's true that $x^{(i)}$ is still "just a number", since it's attached to the variable of interest in the second case it's value will carry through which is why we end up at $x^{(i)}$ for the result.

Comment: Thank you for this! I must say, I appreciate it even more when I consider how long it has been since I asked this question. In reality, I have never had any formal training in any form of calculus (not even high-school level, sad to say), so, while I perhaps understood the concept, the math itself has always been a bit fuzzy. Interestingly enough, I started trying to learn basic differential (univariate) calculus around 2 weeks ago, and I think you may have given me a sneak peek. I'm glad to say that your answer was very helpful, thinking back on the course. Once more, thank you!

Comment: When you were explaining the derivation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0}$, in the final form you retained the $\frac{1}{2m}$ while at the same time having $\frac{1}{m}$ as the outer term. I suspect this is a simple transcription error?

Comment: @voithos yup -- good catch. Just noticed that myself on the Coursera forums where I cross posted. Typing in LaTeX is tricky business! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @voithos: also, I posted so long after because I just started the same class on it's next go-around. I *have* taken multivariable calculus and didn't get the derivation... so I re-taught myself. I knew the gist of taking a partial with respect to a variable, but the chain rule part was missing. After I figured it out, I added the same answer to the Coursera forum where someone had asked the same, and that linked here. The other answer is plenty fine, but it wouldn't quite have gotten things to click for me, so I thought I'd give it a whirl in my own words.

Comment: I see - best wishes on your classes! 'Tis exciting times indeed.

Comment: I have a question.In this part:  $ \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1} (f(\theta) - y)^2$, why does the exponent 2 goes outside the summation, even before the $\frac{1}{2m}$? I'm just starting to study calculus for the same reason as the OP, but I didn't understand why the 2 goes to that place. I kind of understand the power rule, but I expected the 2 to be placed right after the summation symbol.

Comment: Ahh, forget it. I guess I suck at math. Just realized that $\sum_{i=1}  2i$ is the same as $2 \times \sum_{i=1} i$.

Comment: @RicardoPieper Just saw your comment and glad you got it. Probably even better than if I'd try to explain (not that I even had an answer for you!). I think of it like an equation with multiple variables. If you can pull the term/operation out of all of them, it can live outside the summation since it's just being done to each term as you evaluate it (if that made any sense...).

Comment: I guess the moral is "if the result will be the same, why not simplifying it?"

Comment: Do you know guys, that Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera links now to this answer to explain the derivation of the formulas for linear regression? :)

Comment: I'm flattered! Taking his class was *the* inspiration for re-learning how to derive this (I'd taken differential equations in college, but forgot...). And now someone I think the world of has linked *here*! Made my day; thanks for sharing.

Comment: step (5) equal to step (9). But, Why the $x^\mathrm{(i)}$ is [a number] at step (6), the $x^\mathrm{(i)}$ is a [a number, $x^\mathrm{(i)}$] at step (10) ? where does $x^\mathrm{(i)}$ come from?

Comment: I think $x^\mathrm{(i)}$ should be 1, when $\theta_0$ at first.

Comment: @Hugo could you clarify "when $\theta_0$ at first"? The $\theta$'s are your vectors of coefficients. $x^(i)$ is the ith value for the actual data. In the first variant (wrt $\theta_0$), we don't care about $\theta_1$, so any numbers present will end up still being a number, and thus the derivative is 0. For the $\theta_1$ case, we care about $\theta_1$ so the $x^(i)$ will remain. It's still a number... but we need to care about what it is since it's attached to the variable of interest. I can add a little comment to try and explain above. Give me a half a day or so.

Comment: @Hugo I just added an added section at the bottom, removing vectorization (no sums/ith stuff) to try and answer what I think you're asking. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: @Hendy I totally understand and appreciate very much!!!

Comment: I think in step 7, based on the chain rule the denominator of the first derivative in the right hand side should be the function f(t0,t1) and not t0 so that it cancels out with f in the nominator of the second fraction

Comment: @GeorgiosKourogiorgas hmm, when you say "denominator" do you mean the $\partial\theta_0$ in $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_0}$? If so, that is just saying "take the partial derivative with respect to $\theta_0$", there's not a multiplication or cancelling out going on.

Comment: @Hendy , I believe step 7 should be written as:
$\frac{\partial \ g(f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)})}{\partial \theta_0}  = \frac{\partial \ g(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)} }{\partial \ f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}} \frac{\partial \ f(\theta_0, \theta_1)^{(i)}}{\partial \theta_0} \tag{7}$
Other than that your response is obviously great. It helped me understand! Thanks

Answer (score 37):

Despite the popularity of the top answer, it has some **major** errors. The most fundamental problem is that $g(f^{(i)}(\theta_0, \theta_1))$ isn't even *defined*, much less equal to the original function. The focus on the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) as a crucial component is correct, but the actual derivation is not right at all.

So I'll give a correct derivation, followed by my own attempt to get across some intuition about what's going on with partial derivatives, and ending with a brief mention of a cleaner derivation using more sophisticated methods. That said, if you don't know some basic differential calculus already (at least through the chain rule), you realistically aren't going to be able to truly follow *any* derivation; go learn that first, from literally any calculus resource you can find, if you really want to know.

For completeness, the properties of the derivative that we need are that for any constant $c$ and functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$,
$$\frac{d}{dx} c = 0, \ \frac{d}{dx} x = 1,$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} [c\cdot f(x)] = c\cdot\frac{df}{dx} \ \ \ \text{(linearity)},$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)+g(x)] = \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{dg}{dx} \ \ \ \text{(linearity)},$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]^2 = 2f(x)\cdot\frac{df}{dx} \ \ \ \text{(chain rule)}.$$

Taking partial derivatives works essentially the same way, except that the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ means we we take the derivative by treating $x$ as a variable and $y$ as a constant using the same rules listed above (and vice versa for $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$).

---

### Derivation

We have

$$h_\theta(x_i) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_i$$

and

$$\begin{equation} J(\theta_0, \theta_1) = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)^2\end{equation}.$$

We first compute

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_0}h_\theta(x_i)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_0}(\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_i)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_0}\theta_0 + \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_0}\theta_1 x_i =1+0=1,$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1}h_\theta(x_i) =\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1}(\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_i)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1}\theta_0 + \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1}\theta_1 x_i =0+x_i=x_i,$$

which we will use later. Now we want to compute the partial derivatives of $J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$. We can actually do both at once since, for $j = 0, 1,$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j} J(\theta_0, \theta_1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\left[\frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)^2\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)^2 \  \text{(by linearity of the derivative)}$$

$$= \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m 2(h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}(h_\theta(x_i)-y_i) \ \text{(by the chain rule)}$$

$$= \frac{1}{2m}\cdot 2\sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}h_\theta(x_i)-\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}y_i\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}h_\theta(x_i)-0\right]$$

$$=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}h_\theta(x_i).$$

Finally substituting for $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}h_\theta(x_i)$ gives us

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_0} J(\theta_0, \theta_1) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x_i)-y_i),$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1} J(\theta_0, \theta_1) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)x_i.$$

---

### Intuition for partial derivatives

So what are partial derivatives anyway? In one variable, we can assign a single number to a function $f(x)$ to best describe the rate at which that function is changing at a given value of $x$; this is precisely the derivative $\frac{df}{dx}$of $f$ at that point. We would like to do something similar with functions of several variables, say $g(x,y)$, but we immediately run into a problem. In one variable, we can only change the independent variable in two directions, forward and backwards, and the change in $f$ is equal and opposite in these two cases. (For example, if $f$ is increasing at a rate of 2 per unit increase in $x$, then it's decreasing at a rate of 2 per unit decrease in $x$.)

With more variables we suddenly have infinitely many different directions in which we can move from a given point and we may have different rates of change depending on which direction we choose. So a single number will no longer capture how a multi-variable function is changing at a given point. However, there are certain specific directions that are easy (well, easier) and natural to work with: the ones that run parallel to the coordinate axes of our independent variables. These resulting rates of change are called partial derivatives. (For example, $g(x,y)$ has partial derivatives $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ from moving parallel to the x and y axes, respectively.) Even though there are infinitely many different directions one can go in, it turns out that these partial derivatives give us enough information to compute the rate of change for any other direction. (Strictly speaking, this is a slight white lie. There are functions where the all the partial derivatives exist at a point, but the function is not considered differentiable at that point. This happens when the graph is not sufficiently "smooth" there.)

In particular, the gradient $\nabla g = (\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y})$ specifies the direction in which g increases most rapidly at a given point and $-\nabla g = (-\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}, -\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})$ gives the direction in which g decreases most rapidly; this latter direction is the one we want for gradient descent. This makes sense for this context, because we want to decrease the cost and ideally as quickly as possible.

---

### A higher level approach

For the interested, there *is* a way to view $J$ as a simple composition, namely

$$J(\mathbf{\theta}) = \frac{1}{2m} \|\mathbf{h_\theta}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y}\|^2 = \frac{1}{2m} \|X\mathbf{\theta}-\mathbf{y}\|^2.$$

Note that $\mathbf{\theta}$, $\mathbf{h_\theta}(\mathbf{x})$, $\mathbf{x}$, and $\mathbf{y}$, are now *vectors*. Using more advanced notions of the derivative (i.e. the total derivative or Jacobian), the multivariable chain rule, and a tiny bit of linear algebra, one can actually differentiate this directly to get

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial\mathbf{\theta}} = \frac{1}{m}(X\mathbf{\theta}-\mathbf{y})^\top X.$$

The transpose of this is the gradient $\nabla_\theta J = \frac{1}{m}X^\top (X\mathbf{\theta}-\mathbf{y})$. Setting this gradient equal to $\mathbf{0}$ and solving for $\mathbf{\theta}$ is in fact exactly how one derives the explicit formula for linear regression.

Comment: I can't figure out how to see revisions/suggested edits. Could you clarify on the **major errors**? It looks like we end up at the same answer, and from what I can tell we just defined $h(x)$ and $J(\theta)$ differently, but the substitutions and chain rule still work out. It's been a long time since I wrote the answer, so it's a bit tricky to re-enter the mindset... I'm happy to fix any issues you've found!

Comment: Also, when I look at my equations (1) and (2), I see $f()$ and $g()$ defined; when I substitute $f()$ into $g()$, I get the same thing you do when I substitute your $h(x)$ into your $J(\theta_i)$ cost function... both end up the same. Just trying to understand the issue/error. Do you see it differently?

Comment: Sorry this took so long to respond to. I think there is some confusion about what you mean by "substituting into". Both $f^{(i)}$ and $g$ as you wrote them above are functions of two variables that output a real number. There is no meaningful way to plug $f^{(i)}$ into $g$; the composition simply isn't defined. In fact, the way you've written $g$ depends on the definition of $f^{(i)}$ to begin with, but not in a way that is well-defined by composition.

Comment: For example, if $x^{(i)}=3$ and $y^{(i)}=4$, then $$f^{(i)}(1,2) = 1 + 2x^{(i)}-y^{(i)}= 1+2\cdot3-4=3.$$ If your composition made sense, how would you evaluate $g(f^{(i)}(1,2))=g(4)$? What would this mean? The types of objects simply aren't compatible.

Comment: Here is what is a well-defined composition if you find my presentation confusing: $\frac{1}{2m}(f^{(i)}(\theta_0,\theta_1))^2$. The chain rule applies to each them (one for every $i$). However, $g$ is the _sum_ of such compositions so you must break up the derivative across the terms of the sum. Notice that if your equation $(7)$ was correct, the derivative would be a product, not a sum.

Comment: Ok last comment unless you respond. Looking closer at your second comment, I think I notice that you think I am substituting $h_{\theta}$ into $J$, but I'm not in the sense required for the chain rule. The former is a part of the definition of the latter, but it isn't a composition.

Comment: A correction: that should be $g(f^{(i)}(1,2))=g(3)$ above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I follow the composition bit, and hadn't thought of that before. You don't define $g()$ so I don't know what it would be. I'll have to think on this more as I really don't know how to correct. Re. eq. 7, I didn't spell out $f()$, but it entails a summation which comes back through when I substitute it in, or at least that's what it looks like?

Comment: You could define $g(x) = x^2$. Then 

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} g(f^{(i)}(\theta_0,\theta_1))$$

but

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1) \neq g\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} f^{(i)}(\theta_0,\theta_1)\right).$$

Then you take derivatives term by term. The chain rule applies to each term. I think if you make those changes, you can fix your answer.

Comment: Those aren't the only changes needed by the way. There are numerous errors, including the statement of the chain rule itself. Sorry if it feels like I'm being hard on you Hendy. This stuff is easy to get confused by. :-)

Comment: I'm certainly willing to fix any errors, and didn't mean to mislead anyone! It will take me a bit to dig around a bit as I'm definitely still confused and it's been a long time since I wrapped my head around this to try and explain it. I only wrote the answer as I googled for the derivation and found this question (with no answers I found explanatory). Yours would go a lot further for me if you expanded to step-by-step. I find yours to be pretty whirlwind-y.

Comment: I assume only good intentions, I assure you. Thanks for the feedback. I'll make some edits when I have the chance. Mathematical training can lead one to be rather terse, since eventually it's often actually easier to work with concise statements, but it can make for rather rough going if you aren't fluent. It should tell you something that I thought I was actually going step-by-step! :-D

Comment: @Hendy: I added a little additional commentary. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: What will be values of partial derivatives be like? how huge? how small? I had no clue though I understood the concept. I get crazy numbers like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42346745/3125070) (skip the code).

Comment: I happen to be re-taking (well, finishing) this class on Coursera now so it would be great time to re-write my answer. It seems I don't deal with the summation well, though you just move your partial inside it (so couldn't I just do that?). Also, you don't define $f()$ or $g()$ either... you just say "by the chain rule." I guess I feel my main purpose was to explain the gist of how in the world he gets the answers in a very step-by-step way as that's what the question asked. I think I goofed some notation, but *why* it works out still seems correct. Am I wildly wrong?

Comment: Restated one more way: the "why" is captured in the chain rule (taking the derivative of an $x^2$ function and then multiplying by the partial of the inside with respect to both $\theta$'s). *That* struck me as what people want to know -- what's the chain rule, and how does one take a partial. I think I tried to explain those concepts well (even if some notation or definitions of $f()$ and $g()$ themselves aren't exactly right).

Comment: The issue around sums is crucial, not a minor point. I know it seems pedantic, but if you are careless with details you can derive utter nonsense quite easily. You're right that I don't thoroughly explain my extremely elementary use of the chain rule, but I guess I'm having trouble understanding how someone who is baffled by that is going to follow anything about the rest of a calculus derivation.

Comment: @Hendy, I've added some commentary about how $J$ can be viewed as a simple composition.

Comment: @ChristianSykes I see the updates, but am still confused. You start with the partial *outside* the summation... then you just move it inside and proceed as normal. But you suggest that I can't define g() as I do because it would entail the summation being *inside*. My question was mainly: why can't I just move it outside like you did/do? Put another way, what, specifically, are *your* f() and g()?

Comment: @Hendy All I am using are the following basic facts about derivatives:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (c\cdot f) = c\cdot\frac{df}{dx},$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f+g) = \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{dg}{dx},$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f)^2 = 2f\cdot\frac{df}{dx}.$$
The latter is the only thing the chain rule is used for.

Comment: @Hendy I'm close to simply repeating myself here (and I recommend you reread my earlier comments), but in my derivation, there's no single $f$ and $g$. You have a bunch of such compositions, one for every term in the sum. There's no way to get around that without resorting to fancier methods as I outlined in my answer. (Note that the sum is still there even then, but it's obscured by the matrix multiplication.)

Comment: @Hendy Perhaps this similar example will help. Let $f(x) = 2x+1, g(x) = 3x-1, h(x)=x^2$ and define 
$$J(x) = (2x+1)^2 + (3x-1)^2 = h(f(x)) + h(g(x)).$$
Then
$$\frac{dJ}{dx} = h^\prime(f(x))\cdot f^\prime(x) + h^\prime(g(x))\cdot g^\prime(x) = 2(2x+1)\cdot 2 + 2(3x-1)\cdot 3.$$
Note that $h^\prime(f(x))$ and $h^\prime(g(x))$ are _totally different_, an important subtlety completely missing from your explanation.

Comment: @Hendy Observe in my example that if $I(x) = h(f(x) + g(x))$, then $J(x) \neq I(x)$.
Indeed, $J^\prime(x) = 26x - 2$, but $I^\prime(x) = 2[(2x+1) + (3x-1)](2+3) = 60x$,
which suggests why you can't just pull your function in and out of the sum.

Comment: Thanks for this. I follow the derivation apart from the: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_0}h_\theta(x_i)=1, \ \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1}h_\theta(x_i) = x_i$$ Can you explain these computations? Does it have to do with picking $j = 0,1$ If not, why are they chosen?

Comment: @TomHale Glad you've found it helpful. Since you said you followed the rest of the computation just fine, I suspect aren't asking _how_ I computed $\partial h_\theta/\partial \theta_0$ and $\partial h_\theta/\partial \theta_1$, but rather _why_. Those computations are indeed tied to where I have $j = 0,1$. I structured the derivation this way because the computation of $\partial J/\partial \theta_0$ and $\partial J/\partial \theta_1$ are exactly same except for the factors of $\partial h_\theta/\partial \theta_0$ and $\partial h_\theta/\partial \theta_1$, respectively.

Comment: @TomHale Essentially, that observation allows me to cut the length of the derivation in half. Please let me know if you need more clarification than that.

Comment: @ChristianSykes actually, I am asking *how*: I'm at the stage or being able to follow but not yet derive... I got lost somewhere after:

$$ \begin{align}\frac \partial {\partial\theta_0} J & = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m 2(h_\theta(x_i)-y_i) \frac{\partial(h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)}{\partial \theta_0} & \text{(power rule)}\\
& = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_i-y_i) \frac{\partial(\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_i-y_i)}{\partial \theta_0} & \text{(defn of $h_\theta$}) \end{align}$$

ending up with a different answer, and was discouraged to try for $\theta_1$.

Comment: @TomHale I edited my answer put in a more detail about taking the partials of $h_\theta$. Is that any more clear now? (Note that I am explicitly _not_ substituting in $h_\theta$ when I compute the partials of $J$. You can certainly do this and get the correct answer, but the extra symbols floating around make it harder to follow imo.)

Answer (score 10):

> conceptually I understand what a derivative represents.

So let us start from that. Consider a function $\theta\mapsto F(\theta)$ of a parameter $\theta$, defined at least on an interval $(\theta_*-\varepsilon,\theta_*+\varepsilon)$ around the point $\theta_*$. Then the derivative of $F$ at $\theta_*$, when it exists, is the number
$$
F'(\theta_*)=\lim\limits_{\theta\to\theta_*}\frac{F(\theta)-F(\theta_*)}{\theta-\theta_*}.
$$
Less formally, you want $F(\theta)-F(\theta_*)-F'(\theta_*)(\theta-\theta_*)$ to be small with respect to $\theta-\theta_*$ when $\theta$ is close to $\theta_*$.

One can also do this with a function of several parameters, fixing every parameter except one. The result is called a *partial derivative*. In your setting, $J$ depends on two parameters, hence one can fix the second one to $\theta_1$ and consider the function $F:\theta\mapsto J(\theta,\theta_1)$. If $F$ has a derivative $F'(\theta_0)$ at a point $\theta_0$, its value is denoted by $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0}J(\theta_0,\theta_1)$.

Or, one can fix the first parameter to $\theta_0$ and consider the function $G:\theta\mapsto J(\theta_0,\theta)$. If $G$ has a derivative $G'(\theta_1)$ at a point $\theta_1$, its value is denoted by $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}J(\theta_0,\theta_1)$.

You consider a function $J$ linear combination of functions $K:(\theta_0,\theta_1)\mapsto(\theta_0+a\theta_1-b)^2$. Derivatives and partial derivatives being linear functionals of the function, one can consider each function $K$ separately. But, the derivative of $t\mapsto t^2$ being $t\mapsto2t$, one sees that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta_0}K(\theta_0,\theta_1)=2(\theta_0+a\theta_1-b)$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}K(\theta_0,\theta_1)=2a(\theta_0+a\theta_1-b)$.

Comment: After continuing more in the class, hitting some online reference materials, and coming back to reread your answer, I think I finally understand these constructs, to some extent. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Gradient descent is ok for your problem, but does not work for all problems because it can get stuck in a local minimum.  Global optimization is a holy grail of computer science:  methods known to work, like Metropolis criterion, can take infinitely long on my laptop.

Comment: @richard1941 Related to what the question is asking and/or to this answer?

Comment: His question was related to gradient descent for finding optimum; just to point out that there are other ways of doing it.

Comment: @richard1941 Yes the question was motivated by gradient descent but not about it, so why attach your comments to my answer?

Comment: the reason why is that you can be aware of other optimization methods, some of which are faster that gradient descent. So please be thankful that somebody cared to inform you.

Comment: @Hass Sorry but your comment seems to make no sense. As I said, richard1941's comment, provided they elaborate on it, should be on main rather than on my answer.

Comment: @Did I have a question. Is there any difference between $(y−\hat{y})^2$ and $(\hat{y}−y)^2$ as the MSE due to different derivatives?

Comment: @Media $(y-\hat y)^2=(\hat y-y)^2$. Does this address your question?

Comment: @Did actually all night I was thinking about what you referred to. They have same equation but their derivatives w.r.t each variable are not the same.

Comment: @Media Hmmm... you must be making a mistake, if $f(y)=g(y)$ for every $y$ then $f'(y)=g'(y)$ for every $y$.

Comment: @Did Oh, boy :D thanks. I was sleepy I guess. What a mistake!!

Answer (score -1):

The idea behind partial derivatives is finding the slope of the function with regards to a variable while other variables value remains constant (does not change). Or what's the slope of the function in the coordinate of a variable of the function while other variable values remains constant.  As what I understood from MathIsFun, there are 2 rules for finding partial derivatives:

1.) Terms (number/s, variable/s, or both, that are multiplied or divided) that do not have the variable whose partial derivative we want to find becomes 0

example:
f(z,x,y) = z<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>2</sup>y
f'z  = 2z + 0

2.) For terms which contains the variable whose partial derivative we want to find, other variable/s and number/s remains the same, and compute for the derivative of the variable whose derivative we want to find

example:
f(z,x,y,m) = z<sup>2</sup> + (x<sup>2</sup>y<sup>3</sup>)/m
f'x  = 0 + 2xy<sup>3</sup>/m

For linear regression, for each cost value, you can have 1 or more input. For example for finding the "cost of a property" (this is the cost), the first input X<sub>1</sub> could be size of the property, the second input X<sub>2</sub> could be the age of the property.  We need to understand the guess function.  For linear regression, guess function forms a line(maybe straight or curved), whose points are the guess cost for any given value of each inputs (X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, X<sub>3</sub>, ...).

For single input (graph is 2-coordinate where the y-axis is for the cost values while the x-axis is for the input X<sub>1</sub> values), the guess function is:

H<sub>θ</sub> = θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>X<sub>1</sub>

For 2 input (graph is 3-d, 3-coordinate, where the vertical axis is for the cost values, while the 2 horizontal axis which are perpendicular to each other are for each input (X<sub>1</sub> and X<sub>2</sub>). The 3 axis are joined together at each zero value:

H<sub>θ</sub> = θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>X<sub>1</sub> + θ<sub>2</sub>X<sub>2</sub>

For 3 input (not easy to form a graph):

H<sub>θ</sub> = θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>X<sub>1</sub> + θ<sub>2</sub>X<sub>2</sub> + θ<sub>3</sub>X<sub>3</sub>

Note θ are variables and represents the weights. θ<sub>0</sub> represents the weight when all input values are zero.  θ<sub>0</sub> is base cost value, you can not form a good line guess if the cost always start at 0.  You can actually multiply θ<sub>0</sub> to an imaginary input X<sub>0</sub>, and this X<sub>0</sub> input has a constant value of 1.

To get the partial derivative the cost function for 2 inputs, with respect to θ<sub>0</sub>, θ<sub>1</sub>, and θ<sub>2</sub>, the cost function is:

$$ J = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)^2}{2M}$$

Where M is the number of sample cost data, X<sub>1i</sub> is the value of the first input for each sample cost data, X<sub>2i</sub> is the value of the second input for each sample cost data, and Y<sub>i</sub> is the cost value of each sample cost data

To compute for the partial derivative of the cost function with respect to θ<sub>0</sub>, the whole cost function is treated as a single term, so the denominator 2M remains the same.  We will find the partial derivative of the numerator with respect to θ<sub>0</sub>, θ<sub>1</sub>, θ<sub>2</sub>.  Using the combination of the rule in finding the derivative of a summation, chain rule, and power rule:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^M (X)^n$$
$$ f'_x = n . \sum_{i=1}^M (X)^(n-1) . f'X $$

$$ So f'θ_0 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)^1 . f'θ_0 ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_0 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . f'θ_0 ((\theta_0 + 0 + 0) - 0)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_0 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . f'θ_0 (\theta_0)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_0 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . 1}{2M}$$

$$  temp_0 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)}{M}$$

$$    f'θ_1 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)^1 . f'θ_1 ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_1 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . f'θ_1 ((0 + X_1i\theta_1 + 0) - 0)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_1 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . f'θ_1 (X_1i\theta_1)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_1 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . X_1i}{2M}$$

$$  temp_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . X_1i}{M}$$

$$    f'θ_2 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)^1 . f'θ_1 ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_2 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . f'θ_1 ((0 + 0 + X_2i\theta_2) - 0)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_2 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . f'θ_1 (X_2i\theta_2)}{2M}$$

$$  f'θ_2 = \frac{2 . \sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . X_2i}{2M}$$

$$  temp_2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^M ((\theta_0 + \theta_1X_1i + \theta_2X_2i) - Y_i) . X_2i}{M}$$

Gradient Descent is

repeat until minimum result of the cost function {

// Calculation of temp0, temp1, temp2 placed here (partial derivatives for  θ<sub>0</sub>, θ<sub>1</sub>, θ<sub>1</sub> found above)
$$   \theta_0 = \theta_0 - \alpha . temp0 $$
$$   \theta_1 = \theta_1 - \alpha . temp1 $$
$$   \theta_2 = \theta_2 - \alpha . temp2 $$
}

Where α is the learning rate